# Replacing a string with underscore character in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

We are facing a slightly weird problem in GNU Make.

In one of the part Makefile, we try to modify a string in order to get right filename.
So "dummy_1_.pl" is to converted to "dummy_1.pl".

We tried to use following way :-

```
MY_STRING := dummy_1_.pl
UNDPL := _.pl
DPL := .pl

$(subst $(UNDPL), $(DPL), $(MY_STRING) )
```

Surprisingly it doesn't work. We can replace ".", "pl", ".pl" etc all this way. However just "*" or "*." or "_.pl" etc replacement strings starting with an underscore doesn't seem to work.

Is underscore a special character in Make. Are we missing something basic here... We are at GNU Make 3.81

Any help/thought is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!.

---

EDIT :-
The problem was posted in short for focused discussion. It seems, the details are necessary. This applies to a pattern rule as below.  There's a OUT_V_FILES target that contains *blah_cpu.v *foo_gpu.v etc various target files. (The special string "cpu", "gpu" etc are part of a list.) We want to derive blah.pl, foo.pl respectively as input file for the rule.

```
DEVICES := cpu gpu memc dram

MY_STRING := $$(foreach dev,$(DEVICES),$$(subst $$(dev),$(NOTHING),$$(notdir %.pl)))
NOTHING :=
UDOT := _.
DOT := .

$(OUT_V_FILES) : %.v : $(subst $(UDOT),$(DOT),S(MY_STRING)) Makefile
      #Body of rule+++++++++
```

Comment: The `$$` look to be your problem in this case (plus the `S` should be `$`...)    `$(info)` can be your friend here.   Do a `$(info MY_STRING=$(MY_STRING))` right after you set it to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.  1) you never assign the result of the `$(subst ...` invocation and 2) you have to be aware that whitespace is significant within the context of string manipulation functions.  With that in mind your makefile code should be something like...

```
MY_STRING := $(subst $(UNDPL),$(DPL),$(MY_STRING))
```

Comment: Thanks @G.M. Tried it without spaces also, it doesn't make any difference. The key thing is, this replacement happens on top of outcome of a pattern rule. We are trying to calculate a blah_blah_1_ep.v to blah_blah_1.pl dependency.

It seems if we try it on a hard-coded string, this works fine. But not on a pattern rule.

Comment: @SS891 Then you need to provide a more complete example -- preferably a [mcve].  Otherwise we can only guess as to the nature of the problem.

Comment: I've put the exact code here. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

In your updated example, it looks like you have some issues when setting `MY_STRING`.   If you correct it to have the proper filename(s), you get:

```
MY_STRING := $$(foreach dev,$(DEVICES),$$(subst $$(dev),$(NOTHING),$$(notdir %.pl)))
$(info 1. MY_STRING=$(MY_STRING))
MY_STRING := dummy_1_.pl
$(info 2. MY_STRING=$(MY_STRING))

NOTHING :=
UDOT := _.
DOT := .

MY_NEW_STRING=$(subst $(UDOT),$(DOT),$(MY_STRING))
$(info MY_NEW_STRING=$(MY_NEW_STRING))
```

gives

```
1. MY_STRING=$(foreach dev,cpu gpu memc,$(subst $(dev),,$(notdir %.pl)))
2. MY_STRING=dummy_1_.pl
MY_NEW_STRING=dummy_1.pl
```